# How to change the Image from Apprequests Dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

How do I change this Image in the apprequests dialog?

```
FB.ui({ 
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Some text...',
title: 'a title...' 
}, requestCallbackInviteOther);
```

There is no image option available for this dialog. But nevermind. Theres already set up an Image somehwere from an earlier project. But I cannot find it in the FB-App setting.
Someone knows where to find it?

[image: apprequests dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This image is your app icon-

[image]

You can change this in the **App Details**.

Note: This image can't be set dynamically while sending the app requests.